# How to fix this error on libgdx project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Anyone know why does it become red or error in android studio and how to fix it?

Here is the code

```
package com.appalyse.deliopblaster;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    private String message = "Touch me";

    @Override
    public void create () {
         batch = new SpriteBatch();

         screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
         screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

         font = new BitmapFont();
         font.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         font.getData().scale(5);

         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {strong text
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        BitmapFont.*TextBounds*  = font.*getBounds*(message);
        float x = screenWidth/2 - *textSize*.width/2;
        float y = screenHeight/2 + *textSize*.height/2;

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, message, x, y);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        message = "Touch down at " + screenX + ", " + screenY;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        message = "Touch up at " + screenX + ", " + screenY;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        //message = "Dragging at" + screenX + ", " + screenY;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

It become error at

```
BitmapFont.*TextBounds*  = font.*getBounds*(message);
            float x = screenWidth/2 - *textSize*.width/2;
            float y = screenHeight/2 + *textSize*.height/2;
```

Error at TextBounds , getBounds and textSize

I want to know the method for fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

1.Javascript and Java are different languages. So your tag should be removed.

2.Java does not have * as valid syntax like you do it. * is just for multiplication purposes.

3.With libGDX 1.6 there were huge changes for font handling. The "getBounds()" method no longer exists. To get width and height of an text try this:

```
GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();
glyphLayout.setText(font, message);

float x = screenWidth/2 - glyphLayout.width/2;
float y = screenHeight/2 + glyphLayout.height/2;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't put * * in my code. i mean * * is the thing that is error in my code

Comment: yes I tried it and no error from that. Thank you very much